# Scrolling a UIScrollView to display the lowest of several text fields

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which has several dynamic views inside of it, each of which has a text field. When I begin typing in one of the boxes, I want the scroll view to scroll so that the field is at the top of the screen (visible above the keyboard). It works great; here is the code:

```
(void)didStartTyping:(id)sender {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, subView.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

(void)didFinishTyping:(id)sender {
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

But, whenever the scroll view is scrolled up to the very top and I begin typing in the lowest visible text field, it doesn't scroll down far enough (short by about 40 px). The puzzling thing is that it works if I scroll down just one pixel from the top of the scroll view, but when I scroll up to the top it behaves very differently.

Comment: you need to log the frames of scollview in both the scenario and check what is there? What i can think of is like bottom offset needs to be increased.

Comment: Well, that would have made sense. But, for now, the ugly work-around was to re-size the subviews so that when the view is scrolled to the top, you can't quite see the bottom view's textfield. Not optimal, but it works for now, and if I do come back to this, I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks Rishi.

Comment: Can manually scroll the scroll view to the desired position - that is, don't give the text field focus, but drag the scroll view where you want to be if the keyboard were to appear?  Can you drag it to where you want it?  Most of the time, when the scroll view's content size tightly encloses it's content, you can't really get the last item to the top.  Another way of saying this is, can you try setting your content size height to be much bigger than the content.

Comment: I have always used TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView as found here: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding. If nothing else you should be able to see how they solved the problem generically. Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way i have managed to do this is to grab the keyboard frame, then update my scrollview insets when a text view gets textViewDidBeginEditing: called. Here im using a tableview, but the same logic should apply to a scrollview, the main difference being how you scroll. I use scrollToRowAtIndexPath, you will want to use scrollRectToVisible

```
//setup keyboard callbacks
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    kbFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
}

//this is called from your UITextViewDelegate when textViewDidBeginEditing: is called
- (void)updateActiveTextScroll:(UITextView*)textView
{
    activeTextView = textView;
    UIEdgeInsets inset;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orient = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orient) )
    {
        inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbFrame.size.width, 0.0);
    }
    else
    {
        inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbFrame.size.height, 0.0);
    }
    myTableView.contentInset = inset;
    myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = inset;

    [myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:activeNSIndexPath
                       atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                               animated:YES];
}

//dont forget to reset when the keyboard goes away
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    myTableView.contentInset = inset;
    myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = inset;
}
```